# Calculating the type of expression `reverse (span p (reverse l))`

Tags: haskell

Looking at [GHC.Utils.Misc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-9.6.1/docs/GHC-Utils-Misc.html#v:spanEnd), I see this function:

```
spanEnd :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

> spanEnd p l == reverse (span p (reverse l)). The first list returns actually comes after the second list (when you look at the input list).

Now, the expression `reverse (span p (reverse l))` doesn't type check, since the outermost `reverse` is being applied to a tuple. Is there a `reverse` function which takes a tuple argument that I am not aware of or does this expression doesn't make sense ?

Comment: Judging from [the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-9.6.1/docs/src/GHC.Utils.Misc.html#spanEnd), they meant `bimap reverse reverse (span p (reverse l))`.